# Magento:Homepage and product page different format

Tags: php, magento

I have been installed magento 1.9 and i add slideshow,widgets and add products.

So now my page look like this:

[image]

When click product in home it shows as:

[image]

May i know how to do, for all pages shows like home page.

Comment: Means you dont want left sidebar on product page ?

Comment: @TBI: No no, not like that. I think themes are different.home page like version 1.9, and product page like ver 1.8.(i think). so i want all pages like home page.

Comment: Have you changed your theme in backend ?

Comment: @TBI:I don't change, just i installed magento 1.9

Comment: DO u want to change the design or layout?

Comment: Check in backend of magento. System->configuration->Design if any theme is given there ?

Comment: @TBI: In themes, there  are 5 fields .. here what i do, i m new to magento

Comment: Yes, what is given in that fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selva,You can be `issue with Package Selection for Product`.I hope ,you have `selecting  Design Page for Product page is Default design`.But by default package of `Magento 1.9.0 Rwd`

Goto admin`>Catalog>Manange Product>Selecting product`  and Click on `design tab`
You need selecting  `Custom design Rwd Package,`I hope ,you have selecting `base ya default`.

[image]

If , you will see rwd selected  `then anywhere in your code,the base ya default selected  as Custom design.`

Or, your `instance package is default ya base.`